# Why did Lord Jagannatha become a beggar and why His wife Lakshmi did not help him?

Tags: lakshmi, identification-request, jagan-natha

When Lord Jagannatha banished Lakshmi from home, She went and began to live in various places. Then Lakshmi made Lord Jagannatha and Lord Balbhadra beggars. As a result they stayed without eating anything for many days. Despite the pain, Lakshmi did not help them. I can understand why Lakshmi didn't help him but why did She make Lord Jagannatha suffer? I find this ridiculous. Why would Lakshmi, the ideal example of wives make Lord Jagannatha suffer in this cruel way? Maybe its a misunderstanding from my part. What is the source of this story and why did Lakshmi do this?

Please clarify me. 
Thanks...

Comment: You should also ask why did Lord Jagannatha banish Her in the first place. This story is also famous in my area. I heard from my Mom that She got banished because She blessed a chandala. Another person told me that She got banished because she blessed a family which was cursed by Lord Jagannatha.

Comment: You should not stop praying... because all this are their own drama for their enjoyment, it doesn't cause any suffering to them.

Comment: By any means is this story related to the story in which sage Bhrigu hits Lord Vishnu in his chest (abode of Godess Lakshmi in the heart of Lord Vishnu) and Lord Vishnu doesn't punish him which makes Godess Lakshmi angry? After this incident Godess Lakshmi left Vishnu. In south India also, this story is related when Lord Tirupati took loan from Kubera for his marriage.

Comment: Hi @YDS this story is from Laxmi Puran